# neo4j cypher query cannot work with property

Tags: neo4j

I built a graph with neo4j. When I searched with the following cypher query it didn't yield a result.

```
MATCH (n:node) 
where n.prop='pro1' 
RETURN n
LIMIT 25
```

I'm sure `n.prop='pro1'`exists. And the query works.

```
MATCH (n:node) 
where exists(n.prop) 
RETURN n 
LIMIT 25
```

Why does the second query return a result but the first does not?

Comment: In these kinds of problems, it's useful to do a comparison of the queries (which includes your assumption of the data) against the actual data. Can you copy/paste the data of the node you're trying to match against?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have to run a few sanity checks, in these situations the usual culprits are typos, case mismatches, or similar. Sounds like you're already going through these, but it doesn't hurt to go back and verify each one.

But if it's as you say, the label on your match is correct, the case and spelling of the prop key is correct, then it's got to be something off with the value of the property itself.

A few things to look for...

- Correct spelling + case
- Any extra whitespace in the value that would cause your match to fail
- Verifying if the character on the end is a "one" or the lowercase letter "l"

And if everything still looks fine, test it again in neo4j...you may want try using `STARTS WITH` in your `WHERE` clause.

As a last resort, try doing a `MERGE` with a :node with the prop as what you expect, but with an `ON CREATE` to set some additional flag on the new node, if it gets created (just as a sanity check and so you'll have something to help you differentiate between the exiting node and any new node that would get created).

Comment: It seems that there is  a whitespace after `pro1`. I rebuild the graph, and it works. Thanks!